# Prerequisites for executing automated test case (coded ui) from Test hub?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Do i need all of these things below to able to execute an automated test case (coded ui) from TFS Test hub on my local machine?

- Build definition
- Release definition
- Test agent
- Test controller

I just wanna make it as simple as possible, no remote execution is needed at this moment.

We are running TFS 2018 and VS 2017.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a test plan containing your automated tests also make sure you have associated automation to the test case.
2. Team Build definition that generates builds containing the test binaries
3. You will need a release definition that was created from the Run automated tests from Test Manager template to run tests from test plans in the Test hub.

When I was first started, this the link which helped me a lot :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=vsts